# How to get started with the code for drawing Blender’s user interface?

Tags: interface, opengl, bgl

I’m interested in working with the drawing code responsible for the user interface in the Dope Sheet & Graph Editors (not the Python code for menus/panels, but rather the actual timeline, keyframes, grid, etc.). How would I get started with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Blender is open source. Have you tried browsing its source tree https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/

Comment: I'm aware and I develop for Blender. I'm just unsure of where the code is for drawing the UI. Not sure why this was downvoted - not very nice for those looking to learn. All I need is someone to point me in the direction of the drawing code for the Dope Sheet & Graph Editors.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but these types of questions are generally better directed at developers, through dev channels. This site is mostly aimed at end users and using Blender, these types of questions about source code don't often get many answers here because developers don't come here often.

Comment: Thank you. I got much kinder responses at http://devtalk.blender.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to [blender.org](https://blender.org) you can eventually navigate to [Code Documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source) where yo will find an overview of the file system layout.  The editors all live in `/source/blender/editors/`, described in the layout as

> Graphical editor code, tools, UI ... (most of the interesting code is in there)

Most of what you are looking for lives in `/source/blender/editors/animation/` and `/source/blender/editors/curve/`

You can look in the actual code, but I find the [Github Mirror](https://github.com/blender) easier to navigate most of the time.

If you haven't already, I'd recommend setting up visual studio code with github addons and syncing a local copy of the repository, making some forms of search much easier.